# identify modified fields by an update query without running it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a lib or a method in mongo/mongoose that would be able to simulate the results of an update query and let me know the what the end result would be, and whether or not a field/path was modified

```
const currentModel = new AwesomeLib({
    car: {
        make: 'nissan',
        model: 'leaf',
        colour: 'white',
        tags:[ 'electric' ]
    },
    driver: {
        name: 'mino',
        status: 'happy'
    }
});

currentModel.update({
    car: {
        model: 'altima',
        year: 2018
    },
    $set: {
        driver: {
            status: 'sad'
        },
        'car.tags.1': 'plug in'
    }
});

/*
    this should result in an object that looks like this:
    {
      car: {
        make: 'nissan',
        model: 'altima',
        colour: 'white',
        year: 2018,
        tags:[ 'electric', 'plug in' ]
      },
      driver: {
        status: 'sad'
      }
    }
*/

currentModel.isModified('driver.name');   // true
currentModel.isModified('driver');  // true
currentModel.isModified('car');  // true
currentModel.isModified('car.colour');  // false
currentModel.isModified('car.tags');  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre hooks in mongoose to acheive this. code would be something like this

```
 Schema.pre('update', function(done) { //be sure not to use an arrow function.

        this.isModified('password');

      } else {
        return done();
      }
    });
```

Comment: thanks a tonne, but I'm afraid your solution doesn't work.

Before posting the question I had tried that exact setup but I realized then that the context `this` in the pre update hook is actually a `Model` not a `Document` and therefore doesn't have `isModified`